# How to get average of column which is generated using sub-query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a query in which I need to get a average of a column which is generated using sub-query.
My query :

```
Insert Into #TEMPTABLE 

SELECT 
[BU] =(SELECT BusinessUnit_Name FROM mBusinessUnit WHERE BusinessUnit_ID = ra.BusinessUnit_ID ),
[Division] = (SELECT Division_Name FROM mDivision WHERE Division_ID = ra.Division_ID),
[Product] = (SELECT Product_Name FROM mProduct WHERE Product_ID = ra.Product_ID),
[Resource_ID] = ra.Resource_ID,
[Allocation_Percentage] = ra.Resource_Allocation_Percentage,
[NoOfMonths] = @noOfMonths,
[Effective days] = (Select d.Division_No_Days from mDivision d where d.Division_ID = ra.Division_ID) / @noOfMonths,
[Efficiency_Percentage] = (((Select d.Division_No_Days from mDivision d where d.Division_ID = ra.Division_ID) / @noOfMonths) * ra.Resource_Allocation_Percentage) / 100,    
[AVG_Efficiency] = AVG ((((Select d.Division_No_Days from mDivision d where d.Division_ID = ra.Division_ID) / @noOfMonths) * ra.Resource_Allocation_Percentage) / 100)
FROM mResourceAllocation ra
WHERE 
BusinessUnit_ID =  @businessUnitId AND Division_ID = ra.Division_ID AND Product_ID =  ra.Product_ID  AND
Resource_Allocation_From_Date <= @firstDayOfFromDate AND Resource_Until_Date >= @lastDayOfFromDate

GROUP BY 
ra.BusinessUnit_ID, 
ra.Division_ID,
ra.Product_ID,
ra.Resource_ID,
Resource_Allocation_Percentage
```

I want average if `[Efficiency_Percentage]` in `[AVG_Efficiency]` column.
Please help
I need average of whole table  column `[Efficiency_Percentage]` in one variable or in a column with same value.

Comment: That is a big sql query for such a question, you'd be better off creating a smaller query to show your problem instead. nobody wants to trawl through that to understand what you're querying.

Comment: I am new to stored procedures. I do post small queries but the problem is people ask for the actual one after some discussion. So i feel its better to give it in one shot

Comment: What table does `Efficiency_Percentage` reside in? In your query you don't use this field, but `Division_No_Days` instead. And as there is just one `Division` per result row, it is of course the one value in the one `Division` record per row. So you are looking for the avarage of what exactly?

Comment: `Efficiency_Percentage` is calculated from other column `Resource_Allocation_Percentage`  as you can see in query. I want average of `Efficiency_Percentage` Column.

Comment: Okay, so you want the average over all result rows. What is the unique key of `mResourceAllocation`? Is it BusinessUnit_ID + Division_ID + Product_ID + Resource_ID?

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, you don't need any `GROUP BY`, because you simply show non-aggregated mResourceAllocation records mainly. What you do need to get the avarage over all result rows is the analytic version of `AVG` namely `AVG() OVER()`.

This should be it:

```
SELECT 
  bu.BusinessUnit_Name AS [BU],
  d.Division_Name AS [Division],
  p.Product_Name AS [Product],
  ra.Resource_ID AS [Resource_ID],
  ra.Resource_Allocation_Percentage AS [Allocation_Percentage],
  @noOfMonths AS [NoOfMonths],
  d.Division_No_Days / @noOfMonths AS [Effective days],
  d.Division_No_Days / @noOfMonths * ra.Resource_Allocation_Percentage / 100
    AS [Efficiency_Percentage],
  AVG(d.Division_No_Days / @noOfMonths * ra.Resource_Allocation_Percentage / 100) OVER () 
    AS [AVG_Efficiency]
FROM mResourceAllocation ra
JOIN mDivision d USING (Division_ID)
JOIN mBusinessUnit bu USING (BusinessUnit_ID)
JOIN mProduct p USING (Product_ID)
WHERE ra.BusinessUnit_ID =  @businessUnitId 
  AND ra.Resource_Allocation_From_Date <= @firstDayOfFromDate 
  AND ra.Resource_Until_Date >= @lastDayOfFromDate;
```